# Design algorithm for CPM advertising in case of publisher

Tags: algorithm, ads

I'm trying to design an algorithm for CPM (Cost-per-mille) pricing calculation as a view of a publisher, for instance:

From Advertiser point of view: Advertiser "Z" create a CPM campaign with $5.0 bid per 1000 impressions, so it's clear that, advertiser charged for every milles till its campaign budget exhausted.

From Publisher point of view: Publisher "X" request for an Ad and our system return Ad "Z", since the model of Ad “Z” is based on CPM, how our system should calculate publisher revenue?

I was thinking that not all impressions are monetized in case of CPM model, but when I ask an ad-network consultant, he said that, no all impression will monetized.
So for example an advertiser booked for 100K imp. with $4.0 bid, should we dived this bid to 1000 for each impression on publisher request?

Any suggestion would be appreciated...